# Android TimeAnimator below API level 16

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Since TimeAnimator is a subclass of ValueAnimator, is there a way to build a subclass of ValueAnimator which performs like TimeAnimator below API level 16? Or is there some other ways to use TimeAnimator below API level 16? What I want is just counting to infinity and correct timing.

Comment: You probably need to consider using nine-old-android library. It has backport to pre-honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea, and it works!

```
public class TimeAnimatorCompat implements  ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener{
    protected ValueAnimator animator;
    protected long currentPlayTime = 0;
    protected TimeListenerCompat listener;
    private boolean ignoreNextUpdate = false;
    public TimeAnimatorCompat(){
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        animator.addUpdateListener(this);
        animator.setDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayTime(long t){
        currentPlayTime = t;
    }

    public long getCurrentPlayTime(){
        return currentPlayTime;
    }

    public void start(){
        currentPlayTime = 0;
        animator.start();
    }

    public TimeListenerCompat getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setTimeListener(TimeListenerCompat listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        if(ignoreNextUpdate){
            ignoreNextUpdate = false;
            return;
        }
        long deltaTime = animation.getCurrentPlayTime();
        currentPlayTime += deltaTime;
        ignoreNextUpdate = true;
        animation.setCurrentPlayTime(0);
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onTimeUpdate(this, currentPlayTime, deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void cancel(){
        animator.cancel();
    }

    public void pause(){
        animator.cancel();
    }

    public void resume(){
        animator.start();
    }

    public void end(){
        animator.end();
    }

    public interface TimeListenerCompat{
        void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimatorCompat animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime);
    }
}
```